# GraphQL query not returning data

Tags: 8

I have 5 different content types and I've added content / nodes. I'm using graphQL to fetch the data, however in 1 of the content types the data is not being returned. This is the latest content type I've added, so I can query data from all 4 other content types and get the data I expect without any problems using fragments.

My query for the new content type is simple.

```
{
  nodeQuery {
    entities {
      ...on NodeGlobalContent {
        title
        body {
          value
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The empty result is the following.

```
{
  "data": {
    "nodeQuery": {
      "entities": [
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If I query the node by ID, I get the following data.

```
query {
  nodeById(id: "20") {
    entityLabel
    entityBundle
  }
}

{
  "data": {
    "nodeById": {
      "entityLabel": "test",
      "entityBundle": "global_content"
    }
  }
}
```

Why can't I retrieve the data using a fragment?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to filter by content type:

```
{
  nodeQuery(
    filter: {
      conditions:[
        {operator: IN, field: "type", value: ["global_content"]},
      ]
    }
  ) {
    entities {
      ...on NodeGlobalContent {
        title
        body {
          value
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```